# $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty } {A^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}$ where $A = 1 - \frac{2x}{n^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Does this expression have a direct answer (as in some known limit)? If not, how can I evaluate this limit please?

$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty } {A^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}$$

where $A = 1 - \frac{2x}{n^2}$ with x of order 1

Comment: What is $A$? Is it a matrix?

Comment: @Mr.Newman no sorry I've edited my question

Comment: What does it mean "x of order 1"?

Comment: @Mr.Newman it doesn't scale with N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{2x}{n^2}\right)^{n(n-1)/2} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1-\frac{x}{n^2/2}\right)^{n^2/2}\right)^{1-1/n}$$

**Edit:**

Assume that limits $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ exist. Then 
$$\lim a_n^{b_n} \stackrel{(1)}= \lim(e^{b_n\ln a_n}) \stackrel{(2)}= e^{\lim(b_n\ln a_n)} \stackrel{(3)}= e^{(\lim b_n)\ln(\lim a_n)} \stackrel{(1)}= (\lim a_n)^{\lim b_n}$$

where:

$(1)$ Definition of $a^x = e^{x\ln a}$.

$(2)$ $\exp$ is continuous.

$(3)$ Since $\ln$ is continuous, $\lim(\ln a_n) = \ln(\lim a_n)$ and $\lim (x_ny_n) = (\lim x_n)(\lim y_n)$ when the limits on RHS exist (which means that multiplication is continuous).

Comment: please can you help me a bit more if you are able to? I'm bad with limits :(

Comment: @Tiana, you know that $e^x = \lim_n(1+x/n)^n$?

Comment: yes so is it now $lim_n (e^x)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: @Tiana, notice that its $-x$ in the limit, not $x$. But, yes, you can evaluate limits of $(1-\frac{x}{n^2/2})^{n^2/2}$ and $1-1/n$ separately, since it won't give you indeterminate form $1^\infty$ like the LHS would.

Comment: sorry so its $lim_n(e^{-x})^{1-\frac{1}{n}}$? how does one evaluate that? is there a special known exponential limit for this expression?

Comment: @Tiana, I've already told you in the last comment, but ok, explicitly:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)^{g(n)} = (\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n))^{\lim_n g(n)}$$ whenever the limits on RHS exist. It works because of continuity.

Comment: oh I didn't know that. great thank you. The final result is just $e^{-x}$ then right? (sorry to insist I just need to be sure)

Comment: @Tiana, yes, you got it :)

Comment: thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Tiana, you are welcome. It is customary to give an upvote or accept an answer that you find most helpful.

Comment: can you please provide me a reference for where you got the expression for the limits above from? (in ur 3rd comment) thanks

Comment: @Tiana, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$A_n = 1 - \frac{2x}{n^2}\implies \log(A_n)=\log\left(1 - \frac{2x}{n^2}\right)$$ $$A_n^{\frac{n(n-1)}2}\implies \log\left(A_n^{\frac{n(n-1)}2}\right)={\frac{n(n-1)}2}\log\left(1 - \frac{2x}{n^2}\right)$$ Now for large values on $n$, you have by Taylor expansion
$$\log\left(1 - \frac{2x}{n^2}\right)=-\frac{2 x}{n^2}-\frac{2 x^2}{n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ making
$$\log\left(A_n^{\frac{n(n-1)}2}\right)=-x+\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x^2}{n^2}+\frac{x^2}{n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)=-x+\frac{x}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor using the fact that $x=e^{\log(x)}$, you then have
$$A_n^{\frac{n(n-1)}2}=e^{-x}\left(1+\frac x n\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which clearly shows the limit and how it is approached.